# Add column with certain value when doing groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame that looks something like:

`df`:

```
date                          price     bool
---------------------------------------------
2022-01-03 22:00:00+01:00     109.65    False
2022-01-03 22:00:00+01:00      80.00    False
2022-01-03 22:00:00+01:00      65.79    True
2022-01-03 22:00:00+01:00      50.00    True
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      47.00    False
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      39.95    True
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      39.47    False
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      29.96    False
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      22.47    True
```

If I do a `df.groupby("date")` my output will be 2 `groupby` objects separated by `date`. This is fine. But what I would like is to add a new column to both of these with the `max` `price` where `bool == True` for the entire column. Hence, the resulting data frames would become:

`df_groupby_object1`:

```
date                          price     bool      max_price
-----------------------------------------------------------
2022-01-03 22:00:00+01:00     109.65    False      65.79
2022-01-03 22:00:00+01:00      80.00    False      65.79
2022-01-03 22:00:00+01:00      65.79    True       65.79
2022-01-03 22:00:00+01:00      50.00    True       65.79
```

`df_groupby_object2`:

```
date                           price     bool      max_price
-----------------------------------------------------------
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      47.00    False      39.95
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      39.95    True       39.95
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      39.47    False      39.95
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      29.96    False      39.95
2022-01-03 23:00:00+01:00      22.47    True       39.95
```

I could probably just iterate through the `groupby` objects as create a extra column that way, but I was wondering if this could be done directly in the `groupby` function ?

Comment: Isn't that what `groupby` does ? Groups your data frame into objects depending on your `groupby` input, i.e. date in this case.

Comment: my bad. misread your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for get maximal values only if `True`s values in `price`. If not match `price` is `NaN` created by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['max_price'] = df['price'].where(df['bool']).groupby(df['date']).transform('max')
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['price'].where(df['bool']))
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    65.79
3    50.00
4      NaN
5    39.95
6      NaN
7      NaN
8    22.47
Name: price, dtype: float64
```